# How to customize Default Windows AutheticationStateProvider in Blazor server app?

Tags: c#, authentication, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server app that uses Windows authentication to identify users.
The app "detects" the user currently browsing the app and can display domain/username correctly.

I wrote a class that checks logged in username and fetches roles from a database, then updates the current principal so that the UI can properly take advantage of the given roles for the user.

I am avoiding EntityFramework and core identity scaffolding code for reasons I can't share here.

Here is the class I wrote

```
public class CompanyAuthentication
{
    public CompanyAuthentication(AuthenticationStateProvider auth)
    {
        var result = auth.GetAuthenticationStateAsync().Result;
        // here I have access to the current username:
        string username = result.User.Identity.Name;
        // now I can fetch roles from file, but for simplicity, I will use the following:
        if(username.BeginsWith("admin"))
        {
            var claims = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[] {new Claim(ClaimType.Role, "admin")});
            result.User.AddIdentity(claims);  // this will have an effect on UI
        }
     
    }
}
```

I also added the above class as a service in Startup.cs

```
services.AddScoped<CompanyAuthentication>();
```

Now, in any razor page, I simply do:

```
@page "/counter"
@inject CompanyAuthentication auth

<AuthorizeView Roles="admin">
    <Authorized> Welcome admin </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized> You are not authorized </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

That all works fine, as long as I don't forget to inject `CompanyAuthentication` in each page I intend to use.

Is there a way to automatically inject my class into every page without having to do `@inject` ?
I am aware that I can write a custom authentication class that inherits `AuthenticationStateProvider` and then add it as service, but if I do that, I lose access to the currently logged in username, and thus, I can't fetch roles from the database.

I tried to use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` but that is not in the scope of any part in a Balzor server app.

How can I take advantage of Windows AuthenticationStateProvider and at the same time, customize its roles, without having to inject the customization everywhere ?

Comment: If you are really sure you are going to use it on every page, I guess you can add it in _Imports.razor.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine isn’t that only used for ‘using’ statements?

Comment: You can also put the corresponding razor files in the same folder and add an _Imports.razor in this folder: [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/layouts?view=aspnetcore-6.0#apply-a-layout-to-a-folder-of-components)

Comment: I never used it for this, but from what I can read, you can use it for more than just `using`.

Comment: I've read your comments on losing the username,...  but the solution to this must surely be to write a custom `AuthenticationStateProvider`.  So first question: Which `AuthenticationStateProvider` are you adding to your services.  Can you show your service configuration in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to write a custom `AuthenticationStateProvider`.  I've set up a Blazor Server site with authentication set to Windows.

The custom AuthenticationStateProvider.  Note it inherits from `ServerAuthenticationStateProvider`.

```
public class MyAuthenticationStateProvider : ServerAuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private bool _isNew = true;

    public async override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var state = await base.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        // Add your code here to get the user info to use in the logic of what roles you add

        // only add the extra Identity once
        if (_isNew)
            state.User.AddIdentity(AdminIdentity);
        
        _isNew = false;
        return state;
    }

    private ClaimsIdentity AdminIdentity
        => new ClaimsIdentity(new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin") }, "My Auth Type");
}
```

Register it in services - note the order:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
// Add custom AuthenticationStateProvider after AddServerSideBlazor will overload the existing registered service
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, MyAuthenticationStateProvider>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

var app = builder.Build();
```

And here's a test page to show you the claims:

```
@page "/"
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider Auth;
@using System.Security.Claims
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

@if(user is not null)
{
    @foreach(var claim in user.Claims)
    {
        <div>
            @claim.Type : @claim.Value
        </div>
    }
}

@code{
    private ClaimsPrincipal user = default!;

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var state = await Auth.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        user = state.User;
    }
}
```

Here's a screen capture showing both the user windows security info and the added Role.

[image]

Comment: You have no idea how much time I wasted looking for an answers that delivers the exact things I wanted. Thanks a lot.