# Blazor WASM custom authorization with database checks

Tags: c#, authentication, blazor, webassembly

I have a Blazor Wasm SaaS project.

The project has a front end normal website that no authentication is needed. I have created a custom layout for these pages.

The problem I am having is the back end SaaS part of the application with the protected pages.

In my MainLayout.razor I have it set like this.

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        @Body
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        ..redirect user to homepage code
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

I need need a more advanced type of authorization which checks database values each time.

When trying to access a protected page here are the following scenarios.

If the account is disabled by a value in the database.  The user should be routed to index.razor.

If a new user hasn't validated their account. They should be routed to the validate_access_code.razor.

I've read the Microsoft docs about policy base authorization but I am not seeing how to do this.  Also in AuthorizeView you only get Authorized or NotAuthorized.  When an account still needs to be validated neither one of those tags exactly fit that situation.

I've spent many hours trying to do this correctly without a hack solution but unfortunately I'm stuck.

If someone knows the answer to this or could point me in the correct direction it would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2c4p6RGtkps

Comment: As there's not much detail in the question take a look that this question and my answer to it that shows how to build a custom `AuthenticationStateProvider` that gets the user and adds additional claims information for the Authorize components to use. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72730622/how-to-customize-default-windows-autheticationstateprovider-in-blazor-server-app/72737303#72737303.  Add some more detail if you want a more focused answer.