# ServerAuthenticationStateProvider is not called on .NET 8

Tags: .net, windows

i am developing an application on .NET 8.
This application use Windows Autentication to Autenticate the USER.
Then I have my own code to add Roles to this USER.
I developed an application on .NET 6 following the structure defined in the following POST:
[How to customize Default Windows AutheticationStateProvider in Blazor server app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72730622/how-to-customize-default-windows-autheticationstateprovider-in-blazor-server-app)

and work really well.
But when I tried to replicate the code on .NET 8, this stop working.

The principal differences that I detected exists on Program.cs

.NET 6
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();

.NET 8
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents().AddInteractiveServerComponents();
builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();

The problem is that MyAuthenticationStateProvider is never called.

I made a workarround calling from MainLayout.razor

```
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider Auth;
@code{
    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            var state = await Auth.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        }
}
```

This call the method and add the roles correctly. But _isNew stop working.

Thanks in advance.